# How to pull out shared incidence between defined sets of columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make specific comparisons between defined sets of columns such that both columns have a non-zero value for the row factor. Then I want to pull out the data of interest into a new dataframe. I have code that works, but I would like help simplifying this into a for loop where the defined contrasts are given (A&C, B&C, D&F, E&F, G&H).

Here is my code that works using dplyr in R.

```
# make an example dataframe
a<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
b<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
c<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
d<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
e<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
f<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
g<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)
h<-sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE)

x <- data.frame("A" = a, "B"=b , "C"=c, "D"=d, "E" = e, "F"=f , "G"=g, "H"=h, "ID" = seq(1000,1099))

# use dplyr to compare and pull out data of interest
AC<- x %>% 
   select(ID,`A`,`C`) %>%
   filter(`A` > 0 , `C` > 0)%>%
   select(-c(`C`))

BC<- x %>% 
  select(ID,`B`,`C`) %>%
  filter(`B` > 0 , `C` > 0) %>%
  select(-c(`C`))


DF<- x %>% 
  select(ID,`D`,`F`) %>%
  filter(`D` > 0 , `F` > 0) %>%
  select(-c(`F`))

EF<- x %>% 
  select(ID,`E`,`F`) %>%
  filter(`E` > 0 , `F` > 0)%>%
  select(-c(`F`))

GH<- x %>% 
  select(ID,`G`,`H`) %>%
  filter(`G` > 0 , `H` > 0)%>%
  select(-c(`H`))

# use dplyr to combine
new_x<-full_join(AC,BC, by='ID')
new_x<-full_join(new_x,DF, by='ID')
new_x<-full_join(new_x,EF, by='ID')
new_x<-full_join(new_x,GH, by='ID')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reduce` from the `purrr` package to simplify the last part. We can also design a function to simplify the code.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create two vecotrs showing the variables you are interested in
interest1 <- c("A", "B", "D", "E", "G")
interest2 <- c("C", "C", "F", "F", "H")

# Design a function to do the compare
compare <- function(int1, int2, dat){
  dat2 <- dat %>% 
    select(ID, int1, int2) %>%
    filter(!!sym(int1) > 0 , !!sym(int2) > 0)%>%
    select(-int2)
  return(dat2)
}

# Loop through interest1 and interest2
new_x <- map2(interest1, interest2, compare, dat = x) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "ID")
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this solves your question, please consider to accept it as the answer.